# unable to install Lightning testing service- aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-testing-service

I'm reading [LTS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_testing_install.htm) article. I was trying on install it via Salesforce dx.
When I use this command as per above article:

```
sfdx force:lightning:test:install
```

it gives me below error :

```
    Warning: force:lightning:test:install is not a sfdx command.
Did you mean force:lightning:test:create? [y/n]:
```

I then ran help command and found only supported command is :

> COMMANDS   force:lightning:test:create  create a Lightning test

Que is then how to get "sfdx force:lightning:test:install" working, when it doesn't seem to be supported?

Comment: Did you install [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)?

Comment: yes , I have salesforce CLI.. able to run all other CLI  commands

Comment: It is probably a version issue. I cannot see this command listed in SF docs so it might be available on other versions of CLI (beta maybe) or requires some other plugin to be installed : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_lightning.htm#cli_reference_force_lightning_lwc_test_setup

Comment: Yup, you might be true, but documentation doesn't give any clarity on this. so quiet confusing!